# using isnull on a column from a joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following 2 tables:

```
 city_code  city_name
    1   Berlin
    2   Munich
    3   Bonn
    4   Frankfurt

city_code   Customer_number
1   A
2   B
1   C
1   D
3   E
```

The following code works and it gives me the number of customers for each city, but it gives me null for Frankfurt, because there are no customers:

```
select c.cityName, c.cityCode, isnull(s.customerCount,0)
from cities as c
left join
(
select city_code, count (customerNumber) as CustomerCount
from subscribers
group by city_code
) as s
on c.cityCode = s.city_code
group by cityName;
```

Now I want to do the same thing, but show 0 instead of a null. In order to do that I used the same code, but changed the first line to:

```
select c.cityName, c.cityCode, isnull(s.customerCount,0)
```

This doesn't work. I am working on an online environment (w3schools) which doesn't specify the error, only indicates that there is an error.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using `subquery` you can direct do the `JOIN` :

```
select c.city_name, c.city_code, count(s.customer_number) as CustomerCount
from cities c left join 
     subscribers s
     on s.city_code = c.city_code
group by c.city_name, c.city_code;
```